# How to view full resolution raster image when delivered as a raster pyramid

Tags: qgis, raster, image-pyramids

I been given raster data in what I assume is a raster pyramid from a client, and I cannot understand how best to bring it together as a full resolution image in QGIS. The tifs are broken into small, square sections and are semi transparent, the image seems to come together by overlaying a bunch of them on top of each other. Am I missing something obvious here? Or do I need to use a software program other than QGIS to analyse this imagery, or is there a particular tool in QGIS I can use to rebuild the raster from the pyramids?
[image: Stacked raster images in QGIS]

Comment: "Pyramids" are a method and a concept but not really the name of a format. What is your file format? Do you have multiple files? Do you have a full resolution file?

Comment: Thanks, I think I was assuming the pyramid method was used to break up the original raster, but I could also be wrong! There are multiple (many) rasters, each of the squares in the screenshot are separate rasters which are all semi-transparent and overlapping. I don't have the full resolution file, which is what I would ideally like to obtain from the many rasters I have. (I have updated my question based on your feedback, to make it clearer)

Comment: Huh, that is some weird stuff! Did you set the transparency? I think I would try to find a non-overlapping, contiguous set of files on the same, highest possible zoom level/scale and *merge* that, if not possible I would either scream at the client to give me a sane data package or run away with my hands above my head.